# How to prevent DependencyObjects sharing their DependencyProperties across all instances?

Tags: c#, wpf

I must have the syntax wrong somehow.  For some reason, my dependency objects are behaving like they're static.  I have something along the lines of the following:

```
public void main()
{
    MyClass C1 = new MyClass();
    MyClass C2 = new MyClass();

    C1.StringCollection.Add("Test1");
    Console.WriteLine(C2.StringCollection.First());
}

public class MyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty StringCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "StringCollection",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
        typeof(MyClass),
        new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>()));

    public ObservableCollection<string> StringCollection
    {
        get { return(ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(StringCollectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StringCollectionProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

gives the following output:

```
Test1
```

Elements added to C2 will be available in the StringCollection of C1, and vice-versa.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `DependencyProperty` will keep value per object but it shares its default value, in your case `ObservableCollection<string>`. If it is a reference type it will be same value. Initialise it with null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact same behavior is mentioned in this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563(v=vs.110).aspx) page in the `Aquarium` and `Fishes` example.

Quoting excerpts from the same page modified slightly:

> This is because each MyClass added the String to the default value collection, which resulted from a single constructor call in the metadata and is therefore shared between all instances. This situation is almost never what you want.
>
> To correct this problem, you must reset the collection dependency property value to a unique instance, as part of the class constructor call. Because the property is a read-only dependency property, you use the SetValue(DependencyPropertyKey, Object) method to set it, using the DependencyPropertyKey that is only accessible within the class.

```
public MyClass() : base()
{
    SetValue(StringCollectionProperty, new ObservableCollection<string>()); 
}
```

> Now, if you ran that same test code again, you could see more expected results, where each MyClass supported its own unique collection.
> There would be a slight variation on this pattern if you chose to have your collection property be read-write. In that case, you could call the public set accessor from the constructor to do the initialization, which would still be calling the nonkey signature of SetValue(DependencyProperty, Object) within your set wrapper, using a public DependencyProperty identifier.

Comment: It's actually better to use `SetCurrentValue`.  If you use `SetValue`, the value source changes to `Local`, which will supersede any values set by style/template triggers, setters, etc.